# Exposing Ogre functions using tolua++

Tags: c++, lua, ogre3d

I want to know how do I expose Ogre library functions, for example: pitch, yaw to rotate a camera..I want to control the camera for my application using a lua script. I m doing the binding using tolua++. I created a cleaned header for OgreCamera.h but apparently the function is not getting exposed because when i use lua_call in my C++ code, the program terminates with an exit code 1.
In my lua script I write the statement pMyCam:yaw(angle) where pMyCam is of type Ogre::Camera* and is passed to lua. The problematic statement is the call to yaw.

Are there any other

Comment: We need more information to go on here. What is the Lua script that is causing the crash? Where is the crash occurring (in your C++ code)? And so forth.

Comment: C++ code: lua_call(luaVM,2,0); // this is where the crash occurs..It calls the lua function RotateCam(pMyCam,angle) where pMyCam is of type Ogre::Camera and angle of type double. The lua script contains:  function RotateCam(pMyCam,angle)  which contains the statement pMyCam:yaw(angle). If I call the functions of my created class, then it works but it doesnt work if i call library specific functions.

Answer (score 0):

What you seek is [luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html), at least that's what I'm using with Ogre basically just right now. It's pretty easy syntax-wise, you can expose nearly everything including overloaded methods, readonly attributes, enums and whatnot and it works perfectly fine for me.

I'm using it in a wrapper engine that includes Ogre, CEGUI (if you're using that as well) and some other stuff as well and so far I managed to expose nearly everything I need to Lua, inlcuding camera-, scene- and object management.

And yes, it's designed to work with c++.

Answer (score -1):

Nowadays there are some of libraries that allow direct access of functions in C libraries.

Like these:

- [LuaJIT's FFI](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html)
- [Alien](http://alien.luaforge.net/)

Comment: I don't quite know about alien (or the libffi it uses), but Luajits FFI also works with C++.

Comment: No it doesn't. The very page you link to says, "The FFI library allows **calling external C functions** and **using C data structures** from pure Lua code." The most you can says is that you can use it if your C++ data structure would compile as C. But it _certainly_ would not work with C functions, not without `extern "C"`ing them. FFI, of any form, works based off of a common ABI, and C++'s ABI is not cross-compiler. Name-mangling and so forth is compiler-specific, and therefore cannot be universally linked the way C can.

Comment: so is there a way in which i can use OGRE functions in my lua scripts so that i can use them in my c++ code? It works fine if I write wrappers to those functions but I want to try and minimize the c++ code

Comment: I never actually tried, but it seems to me that using those libraries it is certainly possible. But am I right if I say that you are trying to bind 2 C++ libraries together using Lua? Wouldn't it make more sense then to just link them together like one normally includes libraries in C++ code?

Comment: i'm not trying to bind 2 C++ libraries together. All I want to do is call a C++ library function just as I would call a user-defined function. Because it works fine when I was calling my created class member functions. However I cannot do the exact same thing with a library function. I dont know why.